# Trying to build a program that will measure ping and write it into excel file

Tags: excel, cmd

I'm trying to make some program to measure ping and write it into Excel (or txt) file.

Since in not that proficient in computing, I decided to do some research and found this:

```
@ECHO OFF  
set IPADDRESS= google.com  
set INTERVAL=6 
:PINGINTERVAL  
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 >> C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\ping.txt  
timeout %INTERVAL%  
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

That program is stuck at timeout for some reason.

I'm doing that in cmd, but I can use Code:Blocks for C as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stuck at timeout for some reason"?

Comment: It look like this: https://i.gyazo.com/a0b1791ba0f4b83affd3f33159330a15.png

I copied my code from notepad directly into cmd. Note that the last line did not even copy.

Comment: When you "copied into cmd", you were executing it line by line. Note: `goto` doesn't work outside of batchfiles, (so also labels are useless). `Timeout` is not stuck, it executes and finishes fine. Your "problem" is, that `echo` is still `off`, so you don't see the prompt. Type `echo on` to prove.

Comment: OK, I created a .bat file and it's working!! Thanks for the advice, Stephan.

By the way, is there any way to just write down the nubmers instead of whole:



  Ping statistics for 172.217.23.174:
      Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
  Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
      Minimum = 31ms, Maximum = 31ms, Average = 31ms

Comment: Get the line, you are interested in with `find` or `findstr`. If you still need to process it (get a substring), use a `for /f` loop to parse the line.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but could you maybe help me out with this?




Currently my code looks like this: 
  @ECHO OFF  
  time\T >> C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\ping.txt
date\T >> C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\ping.txt  
set IPADDRESS= google.com  
set INTERVAL=6  
:PINGINTERVAL  
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 >> C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\ping.txt  
timeout %INTERVAL%  
GOTO PINGINTERVAL

I need to know the starting time at which program first started and ping.